# Apple Mail not showing attachments correctly from PHP

Tags: php, email, opencart

I am trying to send HTML emails with attachments from Opencart. There is a built in function `$mail->addAttachment`. Everything is fine, except that on the place of the attachment is a white box in Apple Mail. In iOs Mail app the attachment is not showing at all. On GMail it's ok:

[image]

The attachment is available in Apple Mail too, because if I double click on the white area, the attachment is opening.

Here is the source of the message, opened in GMail (I removed X headers):

```
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.39-0+deb7u2
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8"

------=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8_alt"

------=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8_alt
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Some text (text/plain)


------=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8_alt
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <title>Test title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Some html text(text/html)</p>
  </body>
</html>

------=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8_alt--
------=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="form.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="form.pdf"
Content-ID  <%2Fhome%2Fhtml%2Fdownload%2form.pdf>
X-Attachment-Id: %2Fhome%2Fhtml%2Fdownload%2form.pdf


JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAgUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9G
bGF0ZURlY29kZSA+PgpzdHJlYW0KeAGdW0tzHLcRvs+vQGInGbqk0bwfuTl2qqKkbMkRk1Q58mFJ
jkJylzvS7pIu8Q/o5oMuLlfpmB+Un5SvHwDmtdylSyXNAgM0uhuN7q8bo3fmO/POxPhTNIWp89Rs
WvMvszbPvtom5nxrEv6zPccIenvjxq34V2xWPHsVXJo3TCtLoiYr49ykdZQVpsjqqKqqxlR1GWWW
+jtQpUUTk5WmKjNzfmP+dGr+fAoStHKAlel9bLCyH1ympspqHRxHcRwn5vTcJDkP1cfpjXl2ekp8
...
------=_NextPart_fefb9509ef8523a96a17066ecf8472c8--
```

Relevant part from /system/library/mail.php:

```
foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
            if (file_exists($attachment)) {
                $handle = fopen($attachment, 'r');

                $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment));

                fclose($handle);

                $message .= '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . '>' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I just realized that Content-ID and X-Attachment-Id was the problem:

```
basename(urlencode($attachment)
```

should be:

```
urlencode(basename($attachment))
```

It works fine in Apple Mail now, but the attachment still missing on iOS (iPhone/iPad). Any idea?

Comment: if there's something in your "source" code that could be relevant, you should post it. You did tag as php, but no "code" to support the question. If you have any HTML/JS etc. to share, then post it. It could help expedite things.

Comment: make sure that `$message` is indeed defined and if you haven't an opening `$message = "Something";` then you may need to get rid of the first dot in `$message .= '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;`. Check for errors via error reporting, it might help.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I have exactly the same problem with iPhone recipients moaning that their receipt isn't attached to the email!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers must be like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundary42
```

In most cases found missing mime version tag. You have error in boundaries let me first give rules [body of a multipart entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1) has the syntax (only the important parts):

> ```
>  multipart-body := [preamble CRLF]
>                    dash-boundary transport-padding CRLF
>                    body-part *encapsulation
>                    close-delimiter transport-padding
>                    [CRLF epilogue]
>  dash-boundary := "--" boundary
>  encapsulation := delimiter transport-padding
>                   CRLF body-part
>  delimiter := CRLF dash-boundary
>  close-delimiter := delimiter "--"
> ```

The preceeding `--` is mandatory for every boundary used in the message and the trailing `--` is mandatory for the closing boundary (*close-delimiter*). So a multipart body with three body-parts with `boundary` as *boundary* can look like this:

```
--boundary42 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 

...plain text version of message goes here.... 

--boundary42 
Content-Type: text/richtext 

.... richtext version of same message goes here ... 

--boundary42 
Content-Type: text/x-whatever 

.... fanciest formatted version of same  message  goes  here... 

--boundary42--
```

Read the document RFC